# AngularFire2 - Ionic - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

The HTML is throwing an undefined error as if the data isn't retrieved. This is my service call to a Firebase list:

Service.ts

```
 getGames(eventId) {
    var ref =  this.afd.list('/game/', ref => ref.orderByChild('event').equalTo(eventId)).valueChanges();

    return ref;

}
```

My page.ts

```
currentEvent: any;
 gamesList: any[];
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public 
firebase: FirebaseProvider) {
 this.currentEvent = navParams.get('data');
 this.firebase.getGames(this.currentEvent).subscribe((val: any) => {
   val.forEach((e) => {

    console.log("date " + e.date);
  })

  this.gamesList = val;
})
```

}

In the foreach statement, i see the data correctly in the log. It throws an error on the html, even though it looks like the "gamesList" is populated.

page.html

```
 <ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>Games</ion-list-header>
   <ion-item ngFor="let g of gamesList">
     {{g.date}}
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Full Error:

```
  Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (LandetailPage.html:20)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14635)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11619)
    at NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (nav-controller-base.js:460) TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/LandetailPage.ngfactory.js:66:27)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15277:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14391:14)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14737:21)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14669:13)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14392:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15640:42)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15177:12)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12161:22)
    at NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:54343:40)
n.onUnhandledError @ polyfills.js:3
r @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
n.microtaskDrainDone @ polyfills.js:3
o @ polyfills.js:3
Promise.then (async)
r @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:3
f @ polyfills.js:3
t.then @ polyfills.js:3
NavControllerBase._nextTrns @ nav-controller-base.js:246
NavControllerBase._queueTrns @ nav-controller-base.js:185
NavControllerBase.push @ nav-controller-base.js:70
webpackJsonp.184.LanPage.goToLAN @ lan.ts:58
(anonymous) @ LanPage.html:22
handleEvent @ core.js:13589
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:15098
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:14685
dispatchEvent @ core.js:10004
(anonymous) @ core.js:10629
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2628
globalListener @ platform-browser.js:3196
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you add the exact error message in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is because on your html it's trying to loop through gamesList before the data is fetched from firebase. You need to set it to async.

```
<ion-item ngFor="let g of gamesList | async">
```

And if you do it this way you don't need to call subscribe... let the async pipe handle subscriptions for you.

```
this.gamesList = this.firebase.getGames(this.currentEvent)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was another route i tried that results in the same error. I'll post the full error.

Comment: If you don't use the async pipe you can still use the same method your are doing where you set the gamesList in your subscribe(). But in the html you need to check if gameList is not null first: `*ngIf="gamesList"` then inside that do your for loop.